# Bash assign $1 value

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
kill9="9"
kill15="15"

if [ $1 == $kill9  ]; then
   set -- "$1" "$kill9"
else
   set -- "$1" "$kill15"
fi

echo $1
```

I want $1 to become 9 if I type -9
and 15 if I type -15
My script above is wrong.

How can I do so?

Comment: This smells a lot like an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Bernhard I don't understand why you thought so. Its a logical question.

Comment: @chrips If you're streamlining your routine of killing or terminating jobs, there's something in the routine that needs attention.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
kill9="9"
kill15="15"

if [ "$1" = "-$kill9"  ]; then
  set -- "$kill9"
else
  set -- "$kill15"
fi

printf '%s\n' "$1"
```

Comment: keep in mind that this will clear $2 ... $N. If you want to preserve those variables you need to reset all of them.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using set

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
kill9="9"
kill15="15"

if [ $1 -eq $kill9 ]
then
set "9" 
else
set "15"
fi

echo $1
```

Comment: This too will clear `$2`...`$n`.

Answer (score 2):

**A universal solution which can be adapted as needed and which also works for all variables at once.** In this example, we set `${@}` (all variables passed to the script) to their uppercase equivalent. Other changes are possible, as required, by simply changing the `set` command as needed.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "* Before: ${@}"
echo "1 Before: ${1}"
echo "2 Before: ${2}"
set -- "${@^^}"
echo "* After: ${@}"
echo "1 After: ${1}"
echo "2 After: ${2}"
```

```
$ ./test.sh a b c
* Before: a b c
1 Before: a
2 Before: b
* After: A B C
1 After: A
2 After: B
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the first positional parameter while leaving the other ones untouched.

In POSIX `sh` (so would also work in `bash` and all modern Bourne-like shells):

```
case $1 in
  (-9 || -15) shift; set -- "${1#-}" "$@"
esac
```

---

In ksh or recent bash (or `zsh -o kshglob`)

```
if [[ $1 = -@(9|15) ]]; then
  shift; set -- "${1#-}" "$@"
fi
```

---

In zsh, you  can simply assign `$1` (or `$argv[1]`)

```
[[ $1 = -(9|15) ]] && 1=${1#-}
```

(or `argv[1]=${argv[1]#-}` or `(( argv[1] = - $1 ))`).

---

In `csh`/`tcsh` (where `zsh` copied the fact that the positional parameters are also mapped to the `$argv` array):

```
if ($1:q == -9 || $1:q == -15) @ argv[1] = - $1
```

---

In `fish`:

```
if contains -- "$argv[1]" -9 -15; set argv[1] (math - $argv[1]); end
```

There `$argv` **is** the array of positional parameters (no `$1`, `$2`... there).

---

In `rc` (where `$1` is short for `$*(1)`):

```
if (~ $1 -9) {shift; * = (9 $*)} else if (~ $1 -15) {shift; * = (15 $*)}
```

Or:

```
if (~ $1 -9 -15) {shift; * = (`{expr x$1 : 'x-\(.*\)'} $*)}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not strictly answering your question, but maybe helping you address the underlying requirement.)

Another approach may be to strip off any unwanted leading dash at the point you use it

```
echo "arg 1: ${1#-}"
```